# java.lang.instrument vs AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj, instrumentation

For instrumentation in Java, why `java.lang.instrument` is preferred over AspectJ though both does the job of instrumentation equally. Is there any specific advantage of using `java.lang.instrument`? Thanks in advance...

Comment: AspectJ isn't built in?

Comment: It is plugin library for eclipse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are two completely different things. The `Instrumentation` API offers a hook into the JVM runtime which allows Java agents to access more advanced features of the JVM. It also offers a hook into the JVM's class loading where an agent can be notified when a class is loaded and redefine its class file. Similary, it is possible to redefine/retransform already loaded classes.

AspectJ is a library that offers a more high-level view on redefining existing classses. It works with point cuts and join points to explain how a class should be redefined. The redefinition by AspectJ is then either applied at compile-time with the help of a tool like Maven or AspectJ can use a Java agebt and the instrumentation API to apply the redefinition of classes at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

As [AspectJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ) is [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) implementation with byte-code manipulation it's better to compare AOP framewors. E.g. AspectJ vs [Spring AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html). `java.lang.instrument` isn't AOP framework.

Comment: Not the best comparison either as Spring AOP builds on AspectJ.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter It's not absolutely true. Spring has some AspectJ support but the main approach is [proxy-based](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-proxies).

Comment: What I mean is that Spring offers high-level code generation  that builds on top of low-level solutions such as AspectJ which make use of the instrumentation API. Spring is one level higher in the pyramid, so to speak.

Comment: can not agree more with Rafael's comment, when I first read this answer it made zero sense to me in regards to the question.